# "Cannot be let to rely on"

Tags: grammaticality, negation, let

When I think of what I want to express, it naturaly comes as the following sentence:

> Self/peer assessment report - This evidence has least value and cannot be let to rely on, because...

Is it correct to write "cannot be let to rely on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

You want to say that *it cannot be relied on* or that one *cannot rely on it*.

Comment: Could you expand this answer to say **why** it's correct?

Comment: Where would the _let_ come from? Who's allowing whom to do what?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: No, sorry, I can't say why *cannot be let to rely on* is not correct. To me, it's as nutty as *cannot be eaten to swim on*, but I can't really tell you what seems wrong with that expression either. Possibly someone else (maybe you?) can help in this regard. John Lawler's comment raises a couple questions about the meaning, but parsing, let alone deciphering, it is beyond me, I'm afraid. It just feels quite wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I see now that I misunderstood you. You asked why my answer is correct, not why the OP expression is incorrect. Sorry, I don't know what to say there either. I think it would require demonstrating that (a) the expressions I gave are correct grammatically and (b) they convey what the OP meant. I'm not even sure about the latter - just guessing what was meant.